# How do I disambiguate different/mutual type associations that point to the same type?

Tags: rust

I have a series of traits that are mutually associated, and contain further type associations that are meant to be enums. I've left the `Id` type associations repeated in each trait that needs it, to avoid deeply nested fully-qualified names like `<<World as World>::Exit as Exit>::SpotId` but this is leading to confusion now that I'm implementing behavior relying on these "top-level" traits:

```rs
trait Accessible {
    type Context: Ctx;
    fn can_access(&self, ctx: &Self::Context) -> bool;
}
trait Id: Copy + Clone + Debug + Eq + Hash + Ord + PartialOrd {}
trait Location: Accessible {
    type LocId: Id;
    type ExitId: Id;
}
trait Exit: Accessible {
    type ExitId: Id;
    type SpotId: Id;
    type LocId: Id;
}
trait World {
    type Context: Ctx;
    type Location: Location;
    type Exit: Exit;
    type SpotId: Id;

    fn get_neighbors(&self, spot_id: Self::SpotId) -> &[Self::SpotId];
}
trait Ctx: Clone + Eq {
    type World: World<Context = Self, SpotId = Self::SpotId>;
    type SpotId: Id;
}

fn expand<T>(world: &impl World<Context = T>, ctx: &T, start: <T as Ctx>::SpotId)
    where T: Ctx,
{
    for spot in world.get_neighbors(start) { }
}
```

([on the rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6eb63d030c4667bb64e80a0c4d7d269a))

This produces an error on `world.get_neighbors`:

```
 | expected `World::SpotId`, found `Ctx::SpotId`
 = note: expected associated type `<impl World<Context = T> as World>::SpotId`
            found associated type `<T as context::Ctx>::SpotId`
```

and vice versa on some other uses of a `SpotId`.

Is there a clean way to maintain the mutual associations and have a simple typename for (e.g.) `SpotId` so that it doesn't matter which trait's version of `SpotId` is named?

I've tried to add more annotations to make clear that they must be inferred to be the same type:

```rs
trait World {
    type Context: Ctx<SpotId = Self::SpotId, World = Self>;
    type Location: Location + Accessible<Context = Self::Context>;
    type Exit: Exit<SpotId = Self::SpotId> + Accessible<Context = Self::Context>;
    type SpotId: Id;
}
```

but get the same error.

I've looked at https://users.rust-lang.org/t/type-alias-for-readability-with-associated-traits/64044/2 which recommends using type aliases to manage fully-qualified names, but I've been unsure how to get started with that.

**Update**: it's possible to specify that one type fulfills both requirements via a type parameter:

```rs
fn expand<T, S>(world: &impl World<Context = T, SpotId = S>, ctx: &T, start: S)
    where T: Ctx<SpotId = S>, S: Id,
{
    for spot in world.get_neighbors(start) { }
}
```

but as development continues, my functions start looking more like

```rs
fn explore<T, S, L, E>(
    world: &impl World<
        Context = T,
        SpotId = S,
        Exit = impl Exit<ExitId = E, SpotId = S> + Accessible<Context = T>,
        Location = impl Location<LocId = L> + Accessible<Context = T>,
    >,
    ctx: &T,
)
where
    T: Ctx<SpotId = S, LocationId = L, ExitId = E> + Debug,
    S: Id,
    L: Id,
    E: Id,
{ ... }
```

and every caller has to be modified whenever I add a use of another id type (there are a few more I omitted here for brevity). I should probably seek a solution at the trait level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ended up working. Ignoring the circular dependency in `Accessible`, I reorganized types so that `World` only has one path to each Id type, and then used fully-qualified syntax in the trait functions. Then, I changed the generic types in the functions to use the types that implement the place traits rather than the `Id`s, since it's easier to write the trait bounds, including some odd cases like this struct I added that really only needs `Ctx` and `SpotId` but has to provide the bound that they're related.

```rs
trait World {
    type Location: Location;
    type Exit: Exit<
        ExitId = <Self::Location as Location>::ExitId,
        LocId = <Self::Location as Location>::LocId,
        Context = <Self::Location as Accessible>::Context,
    >;

    fn get_neighbors(&self, spot_id: <Self::Exit as Exit>::SpotId) -> &[<Self::Exit as Exit>::SpotId];
}
trait Ctx {
    type World: World;
}

struct SpotAccess<T, S>
where
    T: Ctx,
    S: Id,
    <T::World as World>::Exit: Exit<SpotId = S>,
{ ... }

fn expand<W, T, E>(world: &W, ctx: &T, start: SpotAccess<T, E::SpotId>)
where
    W: World<Exit = E>,
    T: Ctx<World = W>,
    E: Exit<Context = T>,
{ ... }
```

I'm not sure if the bound on `World::Exit` that its associated types are the same as `World::Location`'s but is required but I'll leave it for now.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is require that these associated types are the same type in the definition of `fn expand`, which you can do by introducing another generic parameter:

```
fn expand<T: Ctx<SpotId = S>, S>(
    world: &impl World<Context = T, SpotId = S>,
    ctx: &T,
    start: S
) {
    for spot in world.get_neighbors(start) { }
}
```

Adding the parameter `S` and constraining both `Ctx` and `World` to have `SpotId = S` tells the compiler that they must be the same type in order to allow this function to be invoked.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=25b3622be5b79f8b06c2ab9279b7381a))

Comment: This works, but it's getting quickly out of hand as I start adding more code that makes use of the other fields, and each time I have to add new constraints to a function, I have to add them to every function in the entire call stack. One function currently has an type parameters `<T, S, L, E>` and an arg `world: &impl World<Context = T, SpotId = S, Exit = impl Exit<ExitId = E, SpotId = S> + Accessible<Context = T>, Location = impl Location<LocId = L> + Accessible<Context = T>`.

Comment: @Zannick You probably need one single trait to have this associated type, then. If you can tell me which trait should be responsible for providing `SpotId` I may be able to rewrite your code around that. Is that trait `Ctx`?